# Unsual DO-UNTIL loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

this is a very simple code

```
do {
       $size = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a value "
} 
until ( $size -gt 39 )
```

It goes into infinite loop for the values in-between 100 and 390 but works perfectly fine for values below 99 and above 390.

infinite loop even if the values are more than 39

```
Enter a value : 38
Enter a value : 37
Enter a value : 100
Enter a value : 110
Enter a value : 200
Enter a value : 300
Enter a value : 390
```

Changed the value to greater than 49

```
do {
    $size = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a value "
} 
until ( $size -gt 49 )
```

and now the range is 49 to 490

Am i doing something wrong? 
powershell version is 3.0.-1.-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is, you seem to be comparing as strings rather than integers, so while 100 is more than 39 numerically, alphabetically it is less than 30. To fix, you can cast to integers like so:

```
do {
   $size = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a value "
} 
until ( [int]$size -gt [int]39 )
```